# I can no longer set a base color in Mayo theme in Drupal 7

Tags: theming

I've been using the Mayo theme for a while now, but I was adding content one day and the base color suddenly went to white, and there is no longer a slot for setting a base color in the Appearance settings.

Comment: Is the color module still enabled?